# How do I write a codeigniter badge?

Tags: codeigniter, count, message, badge

How do I count all unread email for a specific user and put it on a badge:
The files are [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B46C63I5qC1ic3B1QXR3Vm1KZjA?usp=sharing).

---

Location code/function:

- crud_model
  // message number apper count per user // START
- header
  // message number apper count per user // START

---

Example: The Admin have 10 message total (8 read message + 2 unread message). The badge show 2 unread message.

---

```
<?php
$current_user = $this->session->userdata('login_type') . '-' . $this->session->userdata('login_user_id');
$this->db->where('sender', $current_user);
$this->db->or_where('reciever', $current_user);
$message_threads = $this->db->get('message_thread')->result_array();
$unread_message_number = count($message_threads);
?> 
<a href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php?teacher/message">  
<i class="entypo-mail"></i>
Message
<span class="badge badge-secondary"><?php echo $unread_message_number; ?></span>
</a>
</li>
<?php endif;?>
```

---

The existent controller:

```
function count($message_thread_code) {
    $unread_message_counter = 0;
    $current_user = $this->session->userdata('login_type') . '-' . $this->session->userdata('login_user_id');
    $messages = $this->db->get_where('message', array('message_thread_code' => $message_thread_code))->result_array();
    foreach ($messages as $row) {
        if ($row['sender'] != $current_user && $row['read_status'] == '0')
            $unread_message_counter++;
    }
    return $unread_message_counter;
}
```

I want to count the total number of unread messages from the logged user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not name a method or function the same as a native PHP function like `count()`. Remove the method, and instead just use Codeigniters `count_all_results()`

Try this:

```
<?php
    $current_user = $this->session->userdata('login_type') . '-' . $this->session->userdata('login_user_id');
    $this->db->where('message_thread.reciever', $current_user);
    $this->db->where('message.read_status', 0);
    $this->db->from('message_thread');
    $this->db->join('message', 'message.message_thread_code = message_thread.message_thread_code');
    $unread_message_number = $this->db->count_all_results(); 
?>
```

Since you do not have a reciever id in your table message, we are making a join to be able to query the current user. In my example I assume that you have the column `message_thread_code` as the foreign key between the messages and the tread?

If this example works, you do not need the custom `count()` method in your controller.

**Alternative 2:** To make the code cleaner, you could put the logic inside a method in the controller:

```
function count_unread(){
    $current_user = $this->session->userdata('login_type') . '-' . $this->session->userdata('login_user_id');
    $this->db->where('message_thread.reciever', $current_user);
    $this->db->where('message.read_status', 0);
    $this->db->from('message_thread');
    $this->db->join('message', 'message.message_thread_code = message_thread.message_thread_code');
    return $this->db->count_all_results(); 
}
```

And then remove the PHP-code and only use this in your header:

```
<?php if($account_type == 'teacher'):?> 
<li>
    <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php?teacher/message">  
    <i class="entypo-mail"></i>
    Message
    <span class="badge badge-secondary"><?php echo count_unread(); ?></span>
    </a>
</li>
<?php endif;?>
```

Comment: 1. From where i remove the method (controller or view_badge.php?)? 2. The table are message_thread with row (message_thread_id, message_thread_code, sender, reciever, last_message_timestamp)
message with row (message_id, message_thread_code, message, sender, timestamp, read_status <0 unread, 1read>)3. I rename count function with count_all_results() and the result is 505 error Sorry i am new......i don't know very well php + codeigniter. 4. If you can provide me the full code.Thanks

Comment: OK, do you want to count ALL unread messages for a user? (as you state in your question)? Or do you want to count all unread messages in a specific thread as you seem to do in your count function?

Comment: I want to count all unread message for a user. Example Admin have 2 unread message from XX message. Student have 3 unread message from YY mesage.

Comment: And it seems that you have not included the whole view in your question? I can se a php `endif` but no `if`? Are you i a middle of a loop or something in your view?

Comment: "2 unread message from XX message"? Do you really mean all unread messages from all senders and message threads for this user?

Comment: At this moment he shows me the total number of messages for a specific user. I want to show the total number of unread messages for a specific user.

Comment: If it helps I attached files https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B46C63I5qC1ic3B1QXR3Vm1KZjA?usp=sharing

Comment: in crud_model the function is located // message number apper count per user // START and header the code are located <!-- message number apper count per user // START -->

Comment: Ok, I have update my answer. I have not tried the code, but its close to something that should work. And you dont need the function `count()`

Comment: You are briliant

Comment: Thanks, great that it worked for you... You should also remove some duplicate `<a>` tags you have in header.php where lots of nested `<a href=` is located inside `<a>`-tags.. Guess they should be removed?

Comment: I have another problem. If you want pleasee see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42718625/display-monthly-attendance-report-of-an-student

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is count the number of $message_threads, right?

```
...
$message_threads = $this->db->get('message_thread')->result_array();
$unread_message_number = count($message_threads);
```

And then send $unread_message_number to your view. You put everything together in your example, I only imagine your model, view, and controller are separate in your actual app though.

Comment: You should probably post the relevant code then, there's no way for anyone to know how you calculate unread email